# Integrating Devise with Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently using this [guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) to try to integrate twitter into Devise.

It is a little challenging because twitter's OAuth does not provide email addresses. Hence the flow of the sign up should be:

1. User clicks "Sign in with twitter"
2. Oauth call back to twitter's callback
3. Ask for the user for email (I need that for my site)
4. Sign in user.

I realized that if the user already has an account on my system with Twitter, I must be able to find the account. Hence I have added 2 extra field to the user model:     **oauth_provider, oauth_uid**.

In omniauth_callbacks_controller:

def twitter 
    @user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

```
if @user.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Twitter"
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
else
  flash[:warn] = "We still need a little more info!"
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

end

In user.rb

```
  # The trick here is that twitter does not give you an email back
  # So we should make use of uid and provider
  def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(oauth_hash, signed_in_resource=nil)
    uid = oauth_hash['uid']
    if user = User.find_by_oauth_provider_and_oauth_uid('twitter', uid)
      user
    else 
      User.create(:password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                  :oauth_provider => "twitter", 
                  :oauth_uid => oauth_hash['uid'])
    end
  end
```

However, I have debugged this thoroughly and realized that if I redirect a user to new_registration_url, the User created in user.rb will be wiped.

How can I do the following:

1. If user cannot be found via oauth_provider and oauth_uid, create a User object with these credentials
2. direct user to new_registration_url
3. When the user have submitted his/her email, create the user with the same user object created in 1)

I have tried using session, but it gets really messy as I have to monkey patch devise's new and create for registrationscontroller.rb.

Please someone provide me a way to do this.

I have not been successful yet. Let me show you what I have written.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these 2 screencasts and it is exactly what you want.

You can try it out! He is using the omniauth gem, which is very easy and awesome :-)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

Comment: Yeah for now I want to stick to Devise because those screencast is getting old (someone on IRC mentioned that). AFAIK Devise now supports Omniauthable out of the box

Comment: you can still how he is doing it. You really want the same as he has done. Even with the omniauthable of devise.